# JaxB Java Model to xsd Schema - string length restrictions

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am generating an xsd schema from JaxB annotated Java Pojo's.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
@XmlType
public class Excess {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String code;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Then the generated schema look like this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="Excess">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I am using 1.6 `jaxb2-maven-plugin` schemagen goal to generate schema from models.
What i am trying to achieve is the length restriction as it is in JPA

```
@Column(name="excess", length=6)
```

But using JaxB

```
@XmlElement(name="excess", length=6)
```

Was trying to use Krasa plugin as well
https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools
But `@Max` annotation or any other restriction annotations didn't worked, or maybe my implementation is incorrect.

Any ideas ?
Thank you.
Krystian.

Comment: Using JaxB to generate code is common, but typically the Java code is generated from the XSD. Given that, the community has built tools are much more capable going in that direction. I am not familiar with the Krasa tools, but a quick look at the documentation seems to imply that the source is the XSD and the annotations are generated based on the XSD. Code generation is awesome - perhaps you would find it easier to hand-code the XSD and generate supporting Java classes with xjc?

Comment: It would be harder for me to code the xsd. as i need to generate schema from 65+ models which are sometimes 2k lines long and some business logic there as well... And yes i thought krasa is doing it other way around... presumably will end up generating models from schema.. but still having mapping routines and other functional code in models, stopping me to rewrite all of that in this particular time. Thanks Rob.

Comment: Right, I have pulled out all the production code from pojos and used xjc to generate models from xsd. I know this not solves the problem with the question i posted but, its cleaner and easier to maintain now. Would recommend doing schema -> models rather than models -> schema.